# Chrome debug/source displacement

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, debugging

I know a lot of users had faced the issue. Did somebody solve this one? Maybe Chrome developers addressed this somewhere?
[image]
It's clear from the screenshot, but I'll spell this:
Chrome is misplacing string numbers time to time. And the misplacement is fixed through the file, it's 2 lines miss in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the one way is to simply edit debugging source right in the middle of the process in Chrome (in my case it's: to add 2 empty lines in the beginning of the file).

But I hope someone can advise a better solution.